# Dimension of a certain finitely generated quotient module over a local ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, local-rings

I've been stuck on the following question from dimension theory in commutative algebra.

> Let $(A,m)$ be a local ring and $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module.
>
> Given $x_1,...,x_r \in \mathfrak{m}$, prove that $\dim(\frac{M}{(x_1,...,x_r)M}) \geq \dim (M) - r$, with equality holding if and only if {$x_1,...,x_r$} is a part of a system of parameters for $M$.

Now I can show that if $A$ is a $\mathbf{regular}$ local ring, then $\frac{A}{(x_1,...,x_r)A}$ is a regular local ring with dimension $\dim (A) - r$ if and only if {$x_1,...,x_r$} is a part of a system of parameters for $A$. But I don't know how to show this for the given case. I also cannot show the inequality. I haven't been able to find a proof for this, so I'd appreciate any help with this!

Comment: This is Proposition A4 in Bruns-Herzog.

Comment: Thank you. Though their proof is a bit unclear to me. Why can we assume M = R? And it seems like A3 only shows the equality condition. Why does the inequality hold?

Comment: 8.2.3 and 8.2.4 in Strooker's Homological questions in local algebra give a better proof than B.-H., and show why you can assume $M=R$.